# Unable to import crypto-js library on my js file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to use crypto-js in my js file, but when i call my pagar function in my php file it throws me this error

```
pagoMasivo.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
 at pagoMasivo.js:1:18
```

this is my js file code

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
var pagar = (telefono) => {
    let url;
    let token;

    let datos = { //datos a encriptar
        "identifier": telefono,
        "customerType": "C",
        "amount": 100, //monto a pagar en entero
        "reference": " Motivo pago a usuario individual "
    }

    let datosJson = JSON.stringify(datos); //pasamos nuestros datos a encriptar a formato JSON

    function encriptarDatos(ObjetoAEncriptar) {
        var datos = ObjetoAEncriptar;
        var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("123456"); //contraseña de codificacion
        var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('');
        var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(datos, key, { iv: iv });
        var codificado = encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
        return codificado;
    }

    let paymentItems = encriptarDatos(datosJson);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
    
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            // La solicitud se ha realizado con éxito
            console.log("El post se ha enviado correctamente.");
        } else {
            // Hubo un error en la solicitud
            console.error("Error al enviar el post. Estado: " + xhr.status);
        }
    };

    let datos2 = { //datos a postear
        "currency": "USD",
        "reference": "Pago",
        "paymentItems": paymentItems,
    }
    
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(datos2));


};
</html>
```

I tried everything, including the code in the php html file, but nothing is working :(

Comment: The Browser does not accept 'required', unlike NodeJS, which does. You need to load javascript using the `<script>`tag. [Use CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/crypto-js)

Comment: Please **Edit* your question to show the PHP code.